# object-fit has no resizing impact on image

Tags: html, css, image, background

I need to make a img fill a div while still containing the img's proportions.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="#">
</div>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container img{
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

I tried using object-fit: contain. However, this has NO effect... What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.container img {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/xwrvxser/1780/)

Comment: I already tried - note that I am not using a background-image... It is a img within a div.

Answer (score 0):

Put the object-fit property on the container, not the image itself.

```
.container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    /* overflow: hidden; no longer necessary */
    object-fit: cover;
}
```